# how to filter items with a certain attribute empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I'm using `boto` and `DynamoDB` and I want to count all the items with `Feature` attribute empty. I tried the following,

```
not_empty_ct = db.instance.query_count(                    
    Feature__eq=''                              
    )
```

But didn't work,

> boto.dynamodb2.exceptions.ValidationException: ValidationException: 400 Bad Request
>   {'message': 'One or more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string', '__type':
>   'com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException'}

I didn't find too much information in `boto`'s [API Docs](https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/dynamodb2.html).

Comment: Please describe your table structure and indexes, along with what you're trying to count

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do a `Scan` which you should probably not be doing in your code.